# How to increase the height by the top of an image and keep the bottom fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want resize an image HTML with jQuery.

It's easy `elt.css({height: '42px'})`, but my problem is the magnification of the image is at the bottom, ie the top of the image does not move and it's the bottom that stretches or shortcut.

Like here : http://jsfiddle.net/763wumr0/

EDIT with absolute: http://jsfiddle.net/763wumr0/12/

I'd like to do it the other way! The bottom of the image is fixed and that's the top of the image that increases or decreases.

How can I do that?

thx.

Comment: I think padding-top works there ?

Comment: @TusharRaj if this was a background image, padding would work.

Comment: padding-top don't works with img: http://jsfiddle.net/763wumr0/13/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/763wumr0/15/ change your `top:100px` to `bottom:0`

Comment: interestingly > vertical-align:bottom; seems to do something in the right direction but kind of jumpy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With absolute positionning ?

http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/pss3ysru/

CSS

```
.img-container{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position:relative;
}
.img-bottom
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: In fact, my <img> is already in absolute position like: http://jsfiddle.net/763wumr0/12/ , but I prefer to avoid add a <div> container if it's possible?

Comment: So just add a `bottom:0;` and `top:auto;` to your image and it will be only positioned by the bottom so only the top will grow

Comment: @OxyDesign @Matrix `top: auto` is unnecessary... do not worry about doing that. If you don't put top it defaults to auto. Just use `bottom:0`

Comment: yes, but if I use absolue position it's for positionate my IMG with left and top property like my exemple. If I add bottom 0; the new position of my image will not be where I want.^^

Comment: surround it in a div as he did and position the DIV itself where you want it **Sometimes when you're set on one way there is a better way to do it that is just slightly different**

Comment: @CayceK there's a `top:100px;` in the exemple http://jsfiddle.net/763wumr0/12/ . This is why I specified to set it to `auto` (or delete it).

Comment: @cayce-k if there is no solution with only one HTML element, I will use the solution with <div> container, but I searsh without it.

Comment: @Matrix and with relative position to the parent of the image ? And maybe with no top, and with bottom with the amount of pixels you need ?

Comment: @OxyDesign yes, use bottom insted of top property to define the position of element is the good solution, thx ! But, I have an other problem, like we can see: http://jsfiddle.net/763wumr0/12/ and http://jsfiddle.net/763wumr0/16/ in first case the animation is smoothly, but when we use our solution with bottom, there is a mini-lag in animation, you know what I mean? An idea to fix it?

Comment: Which browser ? Because on Chrome I see both smooth

Comment: your right, it's with FireFox there is the problem... So we can't do anything I supose :'(

Comment: Maybe with full CSS animation : http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/aLqsnw6j/ I only did it with Chrome -webkit- for the demo but you need to add all the others [caniuse#animations](http://caniuse.com/#search=animation)

Comment: @OxyDesign that makes sense, but Matrix should delete it for sure. Just a better practice to use one or the other imho.

Comment: @OxyDesign if I want used the animation CSS3 solution, I need to be define relative value of height (beause I use this animation on many image with different size). Like: ```{ 0% {height: += 10px } 50%{ height: += 10px} }``` but we can't do that no? imposible to use a trick for that?

Comment: Yes you can, with a container :-)
Like this : http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/udxd83Lr/ you set the `position` and `animation` (in **%**) on the `class` for `container` et `img` inside then you just need to set the `heigth` (on **container**) and `width` (on **img**) specific for each image.